# Multiple inline functions in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, inline-functions

I have the requirement to call my 2nd inline function into my 1st function. I am not able to achieve this one and getting error only.

```
with 
  function add_string(p_string in varchar2) return varchar2
  is
    --Function to add a string
    l_buffer varchar2(32767);
  begin
    l_buffer := p_string || ' works!';
    --
    return l_buffer;
    --
  end ; 
  --      
  function doesnt_it(p_string in varchar2) return varchar2
  is 
    l_buffer varchar2(32767);
    pp_string varchar2(32767);
  begin
    select add_string(p_string) into pp_string from dual;
    l_buffer := pp_string || ' Doesnt it?';
    --
    return l_buffer;
    --
  end ; 
--
select doesnt_it('Yes, it') as outVal
from dual
;
```

Comment: Please add the error message you get. Also include the Oracle version as inline functions weren't available before Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible you should replace `SELECT func() INTO variable` with direct function call:

> *ORA-06553: PLS-231: function 'ADD_STRING' may not be used in SQL*

```
with 
  function add_string(p_string in varchar2) return varchar2
  is
    --Function to add a string
    l_buffer varchar2(32767);
  begin
    l_buffer := p_string || ' works!';
    --
    return l_buffer;
    --
  end ;

  function doesnt_it(p_string in varchar2) return varchar2
  is 
    l_buffer varchar2(32767);
    -- pp_string varchar2(32767);
  begin
    -- select add_string(p_string) into pp_string from dual;
    l_buffer := add_string(p_string) || ' Doesnt it?';  -- here is function call
    --
    return l_buffer;
    --
  end ; 

select  doesnt_it('Yes, it') as outVal
from dual;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=333bdcd753cabf8f0455e5a71b3e95e5)**

Output:

```
OUTVAL
Yes, it works! Doesnt it?
```

Alternative solution:

```
pp_string :=  add_string(p_string);
l_buffer := pp_string || ' Doesnt it?';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ed20033b44723595fcfe1c6b51aa4169)**

---

You could also have inline function/procedure in inline with block [Procedures in the WITH Clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1#procedures)